# How to get StyledComponent's type in intellisense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have created a function which takes a component and returns a Styled component of that

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const withStyled = (Component, styles) => {
  const StyledComponent = styled(Component)`
    ${styles}
  `;

  return StyledComponent;
};

export default withStyled;
```

I am using this withStyled function as below

```
import cx from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';
import withStyled from '../../../hoc/withStyled';
import styles from './Paragraph.style';

interface Props {
  className: string;
  sizeVariant: string;
  children: string;
}

const Paragraph = (props: Props) => {
  const { children, className, ...extraProps } = props;
  return (
    <p className={cx('paragraph', className)} {...extraProps}>
      {children}
    </p>
  );
};

const StyledParagraph = withStyled(Paragraph, styles);

export default StyledParagraph;
```

But when I am using my Paragraph component, VS code intellisense is not showing me suggestions related to props
This is because withStyled function is returning me a new component and my original component's types are lost in the process.

Is there a way to get the original types in StyledComponent too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

```
function withStyled<
  T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>
>(component: T, styles: string): T {
  return styled(component)`${styles}`;
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rbqxgt?file=App.tsx

---

The `@types/styled-components` package seems to be a bit busted, since the `StyledComponent` type just resolves to `any`. This is what I get from Intellisense:

```
type StyledComponent<
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  T extends object,
  O extends object = {},
  A extends string | number | symbol = never
> = any;
```

You can use generics to just return the same component type. FC stands for Function Component.

```
function withStyled<T>(component: React.FC<T>, styles: string): React.FC<T> {
  return styled(component)`${styles}`;
}
```

An arrow function requires you to write `<T extends Object>` or `<T,_>` instead of just `<T>` else it clashes with JSX.

```
const withStyled = <T extends Object>(
  Component: React.FC<T>,
  styles: string
): React.FC<T> => styled(Component)`${styles}`;
```

Then, this line:

```
const StyledParagraph = withStyled(Paragraph, styles);
```

Produces this intellisense:

```
const StyledParagraph: React.FC<Props>
```

And you will get type errors as normal.

---

To allow for passing any acceptable types, not just function components, you can use `T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>` and just return the same type, as shown in the TLDR.

Answer (score 1):

> withStyled function is returning me a new component and my original component's types are lost in the process.

Because the `Component` 1st argument of the `withStyled` function is not typed, TypeScript infers it as `any`. This is an error in TS with strict mode.

Therefore, `styled(Component)` is also inferred as being applied on an "any" component, with no information about its props:

```
const withStyled = (Component, styles) => { // Parameter 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type. (same for 'styles')
  //                ^? (parameter) Component: any
  const StyledComponent = styled(Component)`
    ${styles}
  `;

  return StyledComponent;
  //     ^? StyledComponent<any, any, object, string | number | symbol>
};
```

Similarly to @ChrisHamilton's answer, we can use a constrained generic type to let TS know what is the `Component` argument type. However, there is no need to assert the function returned type, TS is able to infer it from the `styled` function. That way, you get the actual styled component type, in particular with the extra props added by styled-components library, like `as`, `forwardedAs` and `theme`:

```
function withStyled2<T extends Parameters<typeof styled>[0]>(Component: T, styles: string) {
  //     ^? function withStyled2<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>>(Component: T, styles: string): StyledComponent<T, any, {}, never>
  const StyledComponent = styled(Component)`
    ${styles}
  `;

  return StyledComponent;
  //     ^? StyledComponent<T, any, {}, never>
};

const StyledParagraph2 = withStyled2(Paragraph, styles);
//    ^? StyledComponent<(props: Props) => JSX.Element, any, {}, never>
```

and the styled component props are correctly checked:

```
function ConsumerComponent2() {
  return (
    <StyledParagraph2
      className="foo"
      sizeVariant="bar"
      unexpectedProp="should error" // Property 'unexpectedProp' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { className: string; children: string; sizeVariant: string; } & { theme?: any; } & { as?: ((props: Props) => Element) | undefined; forwardedAs?: ((props: Props) => Element) | undefined; }'.
    >
      Hello
    </StyledParagraph2>
  )
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=73&ssc=2&pln=63&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAZxgE8AbJAEzm1wPubYFo0uSADskwmLTLlyrJGiYoiHAK7CMwCMLhoAHgAoAdEfkpatJLQBcdGFGDCA5gG0AugEpr9O44rlBw+jgAd2AYAAsAZUYWdgBeOD0AYSFNMRgAGhteWjc4WIA+OABvOAB6UrgABUUUECQYJCg4AHJk8FTxZrgqJmA0UKYGODDTOBQtZvGGLsYwJAME2lqkDmgWnhZaZrdyODKKvcOj47gAPQB+Xe1NQKjeVjaRNLysmKSU0XE3AAMrvYASIobCwAXyu318eyIMGUUC0dxijw6MAoe3Kxwu5BBvnsDSgmHQK0qODAtGKVxMZgAcstPLZ7A5UXRgAAvJAANUUwHGMDp3kZFLCwCYrCIwj5DIoYL8N3g1SgKAcCrAYReejAJKsVU1uQK5L2-kCJTQQpFYsylNoNLqmSMBiQOlsKGJEFJcBBLw1rtoTOhsK0ej+cAAPGBtApqctYkVdHpmmAakqUCrmhaI1blm4PUU7Q6nS7SSD8kG9jHTaKxGCjsHSmBi3s3FLfIb4MCyfF8IImNBrAAjJjKJCkKQygLwBFseWK5Wq+IhcIT1h6KdJlWZNuN8jow6Y8iYVTqTRwZIBZR1KBIz4wPS5IpXP1whJB4OLlczkvh0wZurRgCMHvRCIwggZQRTgYQIHgEYADcVl7JAxDgCAAGsUAYD9aFZDkuR5WJ8F7RR8A-VQHTmDBJxJPDaGA0D2EaHAoHwfY4CAkCwIgqCUFguB4MQlC0KDetjgACSQJhu2fUpX0TGchJ2aVykUxTpH3NQYA0LR50iaI2AAJmDAAVOA8zEVgySnOo8VoYNZiQCBMFeNh8icAAGFx8nedor2sAz1x0rUvAZW8rm3HdLgNWUWJ0h4PmeeJgSXS80h+INATbKs4AhaQoXqf0ovuJLxCZUK9kxbFpBbfKYjfZMwl0l4tMXXTlxk2q-OyTcSt3VTDy0E9aDPRpCpgZrgpymFH0DatpIVVc6o-S1rSQPDMAgCAiJOTC2U5OxcPwwjiNEHQyIaVgCyomiwPo6AmPRAtGkYFoSOOuRToLLpWAgCxwMg4ydGAQIj1sloAElxG8TC0AAQRgele2UBoyQAMmKT9IzqCUfG0csxUxxlmW2nDxDx0h3TgFGSnCJA6nOawplJj0KbGWhaYSdVNWsAscjyQoAFEWDqL44AAHzgVRZEwew2FJ1aoCCRRZFYKGWesPR2e9TmdR5uB+ep5KRbF4QJal1gGeaAxBI-UTxIgSSZunWrdLkrFyCAA)